# Workmanager with Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager, kotlin-multiplatform

I want to call a method in from CommonMain periodically even when the app is in background. I wanted to start to implement it for Android, so I tried with `Workmanager`. But I realised that I cannot call any method from CommonMain inside the `doWork()` method.

Is there a way to solve that issue? Or is there even a `Workmanager` Alternative for KMM to work with both iOS and android and being written inside CommonMain?

Comment: why can't you? it should be totally fine to call commonMain method from androidMain. on iOS you'll have to do platform level call too, I don't think there's a lib to handle this scenario for you from common

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't even try that^^ I tried implementing the worker class in androidApp. thanks for the tip